# Raspberry Pi 7 inch Touchscreen rotate

Tags: python, touch, screen, kivy

I have a small problem:
I would like using Raspberry PI 7 inch LCD on portrait (standing) mode. (Kivy application)
I added on /boot/config.txt: lcd_rotate=2 and display_rotate=1
The display is OK, but touch screen not good! The touch not rotating 90 degrees.
How I rotate touch screen 90 degrees?

Comment: Have you asked on the raspberry pi forum? There are lots of threads about this there.

Comment: I asked this on Raspberry forum. :-)

Comment: Did you resolve the issue ?

Comment: Yes and no. I used PyQt 
instead of Kivy.

Answer (score 1):

## Rotate official 7" Raspberry Touchscreen

1.**install xinput**:

```
sudo apt-get install xinput
```

2.**to rotate the screen, edit this file:**

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

and add this line at the end:

```
display_rotate=1
```

for the other direction, you can use:

```
display_rotate=3
```

exit(CTRL+X) and save.

3.**create a script for flipping touchscreen every time raspbian boots:**

```
sudo nano /home/pi/Desktop/fliptouch.sh
```

add this line:

```
xinput --set-prop 'FT5406 memory based driver' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
```

exit(CTRL+X) and save.

4.**chmod this script:**

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/pi/Desktop/fliptouch.sh
```

5.**to launch the script with the session, edit this file:**

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

add this line at the end:

```
@/home/pi/Desktop/fliptouch.sh
```

exit(CTRL+X) and save.

6.**Reboot**:

```
sudo reboot
```

**source**: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=120793&start=50#p1084567